# Scrapy correct form data but cant login

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I already managed on some webpages to successfully log in and start scraping data, but i noticed, that i got some big problems with other pages.
I checked in GoogleChrome the form data and there is only username and password to fill in, so i did it in my code, but i cant login...

**My Code**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from ..items import DuifloginItem
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
import csv

class DuifLogin(CrawlSpider):
    name = "duiflogin"
    allowed_domains = ['duif.nl']
    login_page = 'https://www.duif.nl/login'
    custom_settings = {'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS' : ['SKU', 'Title', 'Price', 'Link', 'Title_small', 'NL_PL_PC', 'Description' ] }
    with open("duifonlylinks.csv","r") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        start_urls = [items['Link'] for items in reader]
        
    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(),
            callback='parse_page',
            follow=True
            ),
    )         
    
    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(
            url=self.login_page,
            callback=self.parse,
            dont_filter=True
        )    

    def parse(self, response):
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={
            'username' : 'not real',
            'password' : 'login data',
        },  callback=self.after_loging)

    def after_loging(self, response):
        accview = response.xpath('//div[@class="c-accountbox clearfix js-match-height"]/h3')
        if accview:
            print('success')
        else:
            print(':(') 

        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield response.follow(url=url, callback=self.parse_page)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        productpage = response.xpath('//div[@class="product-details col-md-12"]')
        
        if not productpage:
            print('No product', response.url)

        for a in productpage:
            
            items = DuifloginItem()
            items['Link'] = response.url
            items['SKU'] = response.xpath('//p[@class="desc"]/text()').get().strip()
            items['Price'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="regular"]/text()').get()
            items['Title'] = response.xpath('//h1[@class="product-title"]/text()').get()
            items['Title_small'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="left"]/p/text()').get()
            items['NL_PL_PC'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="desc"]/ul/li/em/text()').getall()
            items['Description'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="item"]/p/text()').getall()
            yield items
```

Here you can see form data on the 302 POST:
[image]

Do i miss cookies? If yes, i cant find any on the whole domain...

Comment: Have you checked the cookies and other headers of the web browser request?

Comment: @Gallaecio, imo i checked every task in the networking-Tab in my browsers devtools